# @Controller and @RequestMapping in custom error controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have application that uses `swagger` and `websocket` beside regular REST. Swagger has default endpoint `/api/swagger-ui.html` and websocket has default endpoint `/api/websocket`.

I wanted to implement the custom controller that would redirect internal errors to a page. Originally I did it like this

```
@Controller("/error")
public class ErrorPageController implements ErrorController {
    ....    
    @GetMapping
    public String handleGetError(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return handleError(request);
    }
    ....
```

However it led to redirects when I used swagger and websocket endpoints. When I changed it

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/error")
public class ErrorPageController
```

It started to work fine. Why is that?

Comment: Can you provide your ErrorController interface code ?

Comment: @Anidg.B the ErrorController will be the spring ErrorController interface so they will not have made it themselves  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/error/ErrorController.html

Comment: Ok. I have seen. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with `@Controller("/error")`

According to [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.html):

`@Controller`

> The annotation serves as a specialization of @Component, allowing for
>   implementation classes to be autodetected through classpath scanning.
>   It is typically used in combination with annotated handler methods
>   based on the RequestMapping annotation.

The optional element that you can pass :

`@Controller(String value)`

> The value may indicate a suggestion for a logical component name, to
>   be turned into a Spring bean in case of an auto-detected component.

It can be concluded that **/error** in `@Controller("/error")` is just a component name rather than a path.

Comment: Oh. Indeed. I completely forgot that `controller` has name in value

Answer (score 1):

Well Controller is a specialized component in spring and the value you are passing is treated as component name rather than path this controller needs to handle.

Answer (score 0):

You should add [@RequestMapping](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-vs-restcontroller) for defining the Path

```
 @RequestMapping("error")
```